# Is This a Software Design Pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Assuming you start out with these two classes:

```
public class Foo{   
    public virtual Baz Bar(){
        return GetStandardBaz();
    }
}

public class Qux: Foo{
    public virtual Baz Bar(){
        return GetQuxBaz();
    }
}
```

Now lets say a requirement comes up to do something with `Baz` before returning it when `Bar` gets called.  I would create a `virtual protected` method, and remove the `virtual` from the public method like so:

```
public class Foo{   
    public Baz Bar(){
        var value = BarInternal();
        DoSomethingFirst(value);
        return value;
    }

    protected virtual Baz BarInternal(){
        return GetStandardBaz();
    }
}

public class Qux: Foo{
    protected override Baz BarInternal(){
        return GetQuxBaz();
    }
}
```

This ensures that whenever `Bar` get's called, the resultant `Baz` is passed into `DoSomethingFirst` before being returned.  Yes this is a breaking change for all child classes, but it doesn't require any updates to any call sites of `Bar`.

Is this a standard design pattern?  Is there a better way that I'm missing?  Also wondering if there is a better post-fix name than `Internal`.

Comment: Is there a reason not to add a method Baz2 (or NewBaz, or whatever) to the base class?  That way you avoid the breaking change.  For the naming convention, "Internal" isn't awful.  "Impl" is also common.

Comment: Do you mean `override` in `Qux`?

Comment: Answering my own question -- the requirement not to affect places that call Baz() is invalid.  The methods in derived classes that call Baz() would have to be changed, and depending on the circumstances (e.g. someone else using your library), you might not have access to that code.   Adding a new method with the new behavior is the better practice.

Comment: I think that Microsoft use `Core` as a suffix for this (such as [`Control.SetBoundsCore()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.setboundscore.aspx)). But to use this pattern, you should start out with it.

Comment: Looks like Template Method to me.

Comment: I keep thinking [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)

Comment: I don't understand the point of `BarInternal()`  Why do you need to introduce it?  This example is really hard to follow.

Comment: I assume you mean `var value = BarInternal();`? Otherwise, your `BarInternal` method makes no sense.

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus `BarInternal` is there just so `Qux` can get a `Baz` that doesn't have `DoSomethingFirst` applied to it.

Comment: @Cemafor ...which is the opposite of what he wanted. Read his question again.

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus I am still reading it as he only wants `DoSomethingFirst` applied when `Bar` is called from `Foo`, otherwise he would have to add the `DoSomethingFirst` to `Qux`'s `BarInternal` as well, asuming `GetQuxBaz` doesnt call `Foo`'s `Bar`. If it did, and he wanted `DoSomethingFirst` applied to both, he wouldn't need to worry about creating a second methond in the first place.

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus Ahhh, I get what you are saying now. That would also make sence.... and probably more.... defenently more.

Comment: @dtb yes, I meant override.  Fixed.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I like Core.  Good idea!

Comment: @Bobson, Yeah, I had a few typos,  Try it again..

Comment: Everyone's answers so far are partial. This uses the factory design pattern along with the template design pattern. It simply combines the two. Typically I'd make `BarInternal` abstract when implementing the template design pattern, though, as I like to separate the templated pattern's implementation from the selection of what is constructed in a factory.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham I would have made it abstract, except that the base class provides an implementation.

Comment: @Daryl: It doesn't have to. Just saying how I'd make it, to better support [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Comment: @Daryl - I still don't understand the point of `GetBarInternal()` - just use `GetStandardBaz()`, then process it through `DoSomethingFirst()`.  No need to change any child classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you slightly change `Foo` class as follows you will get [Template Method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

```
public class Foo{   
    public Baz Bar(){
        var value = BarInternal();
        DoSomethingFirst(value);
        return value;
    }

    protected virtual Baz BarInternal(){
        return GetStandardBaz();
    }
}
```

You can achieve something similar with [Decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) as well. Decision will depend on details of what your classes are intended to do.

Comment: After reading the wikipedia page I'd have to agree that this is in general an example of a Template pattern, but I was thinking that the process of exposing a public method in the base class, and having a virtual Core method would be a more specific

Answer (score 1):

This is a good thing because you can filter the inputs and outputs in a standard way. You can do validation and additional processing.

You can also validate inputs so that the inner/virtual method can rely on certain conditions to be true.

I usually use the suffix "Core" (`GetBarCore`).